# Using Cocostudio UI Editor with cocos2d-x (load json files)

Tags: json, cocos2d-x, cocos2d-x-3.0

I am working with cocos2d-x 3.1 and try to use the Cocostudio UI Editor.

This helppage http://upyun.cocimg.com/CocoStudio/helpdoc/v1.0.0.0/en/index.html uses a CCUIHelper to load the json file and create a widget. This method was removed in cocos2d-x 3.0. While searching for a solution I found a directory which is called "WidgetReader" located under "editor-support". Sadly I am unable to include it, because the vs 2013 project can't find it. (and I am unsure if that's the right place where I am searching)

Does anyone know how I can use the exportes json-files from ui editor?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can try this :

```
#include "cocostudio/Cocostudio.h"

auto widget = cocostudio::GUIReader::getInstance()->widgetFromJsonFile("abc.json");
```

Anyway,the include path should add "(yourCocosRoot)/cocos/editor-support".

Answer (score 0):

you can use the following code

Node* node = CSLoader::createNode("SampleUIAnimation.json");
this->addChild(node);